# How to let IDE understand list of methods and type hinting when generate methods using metaclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, metaprogramming

My metaclass generate a part of class methods, but IDE (PyCharm and others too) can't index them.
For example, I have this kind of code:
[image: For example, I have this kind of code]

How can I let IDE to index new methods of instance? Perhaps am I using wrong approach to create new methods?

P.S. `Units` is just a Enum class.

Comment: A separate `pyi` stub file perhaps?

Comment: @PavelKarateev Can we combine `.pyi` with `.py` implementation? How to implement this?